# How do I convert an array output format?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, string

I have a Ruby narray automatically generated, which has this form: `[x,y]`, where `x` and `y` are integers.

I want to transform `[x,y]` into this type of string:

```
"p\.x\.y"
```

I haven't succeeded in transforming it using a regular expression.

Comment: p is a fixed letter, which is there whatever happen

Comment: start with a 'p' string then loop over the array elements adding the individual elements with whatever decorations you like, e.g '\.'

Comment: Regex is for string parsing, not string generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is used to match patterns, not to generate strings.

To accomplish what you want, just use the splat operator with `sprintf`:

```
array = [1,2]
puts sprintf("p\\.%d\\.%d", *array)
```

This will output `"p\.1\.2"`

Comment: Thanks, it was obvious finally, I didn't notice I could do that way, I was so sure I had to use regex that I was wrong

Comment: It's easier to use [`String.%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-25): `'p\.%d\.%d' % [1,2] # => "p\\.1\\.2"`, which also outputs as `p\.1\.2`. Instead of embedding the format in double-quotes, which forces double-escaped backslashes, use single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way:

```
x = [1,2]
puts "p\\.#{x[0]}\\.#{x[1]}" #=> p\.1\2
```